# PHP-GD How I can check the type (jpeg, gif ..) with a url of facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, gd, php-gd

If a user has no photo facebook instead of a jpeg get a gif. 
How I can check the type?

I have tried the following:

```
$PIC_Friend = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'. id .'/picture?width=50&height=50')); 
if(imagejpeg($PIC_Friend)) { 
..
} elseif (imagegif($PIC_Friend)) { 
...
```

This works but replaces all my template (the remaining elements of php) and only shows photo of accused imagejpg method imagegif etc. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

The solution is simple .. just use the php method **exif_imagetype**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$img_info = getimagesize($file_path);
if($img_info['mime'] == 'image/pjpeg' || $img_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
    echo 'It is a .jpeg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**exif_imagetype**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
$type = exif_imagetype('path/to/yourImage');
```

`$type` can be `IMAGETYPE_GIF,IMAGETYPE_JPEG,IMAGETYPE_PNG,...`.
This method is much faster than `getimagesize`. It will output `false` if your file is not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can read headers with `get_headers`

```
$headers = get_headers('http://graph.facebook.com/'. id .'/picture?width=50&height=50');
```

**Output**

```
array(22) 
{
  [0]=> string(23) "HTTP/1.1 302 forced.302"
  ...
  [14]=> string(24) "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
  ...
  string(17) "Connection: close"
}
```